# TTThumbsViewController on a UIView

Tags: iphone

Hi is it possible to add a TTHUmbsViewController on a UIView like

```
[UIView addSubView:TTHUmbsViewCOntroller.view]
```

?????

Answer (score 0):

Like this is better :

```
TTHUmbsViewController* thumbsVC = [[TTHUmbsViewController alloc] init];
[yourView addSubview:thumbsVC.view];
```

Comment: HI Mathieu Thanks for you reply. I actually tried this method. But the images are not getting visible. The photos are properly loaded on the TThumbsViewController as when i load the thumbsVC using a navigation controller, i can see all the images properly. Any suggestions????

Comment: cant understand why but the app is crashing